# Display Django Templates after sucessfuly posting data

Tags: python, html, django, templates, model

I got a problem with my Django templates:

forms.py:

```
class SupportForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    message = forms.CharField()
```

models.py:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

views.py:

```
class my_view(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            messages = Message.objects.filter(user=request.user)
            context = {
                'object': messages,
            }
            return render(self.request, 'my.html', context)
        except:
            return render(request, "my.html",{})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = SupportForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            message_model = Message(
                user=request.user,
                name = name,
                message = message,
                )
            message_model.save()
        return redirect('/my/')
```

my.html:

```
object:{{ objects }}<br>
name:{{objects.name.1}}<br>
message:{{objects.message.1}}<br>

{% for item in objects_list %}

{{ item.name }}

{% endfor %}
```

I want to post name and message in html and then show it under input. POST works fine. Then i want to display my name and message.
The problem is with viewing my objects in html: i can't see anything. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: *WORKING*

views.py:

```
class my_view(ListView):

    model = Message
    template_name = "my.html"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = SupportForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
                message_model = Message(
                user=request.user,
                name = name,
                message = message,
                )
            message_model.save()
            return redirect('/my/')
```

my.html:

```
{% for item in object_list %}

{{ item.name }}
{{ item.message|safe }}
<br>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the context change

```
            context = {
                'objects': messages,
            }
```

in the HTML

```
{% for object in objects %}

name:{{object.name}}<br>
message:{{object.message}}<br>

{% endfor %}
```

you have referred to it as `object` not `objects`
try it and let me know

Comment: I noticed that earlier but sadly it does not fix that.

Comment: could you try message:{{ object.message }} without the 1

Comment: Still nothing happens

Comment: Changing View to ListView fixed the problem.